# How did he assume such representation in the proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

I was going through the proof of the Basis Representation Theorem in Number Theory by George Andrews.

**My doubt have been put in red box.**
We need to prove the existence of representation (1-2-1). Right? I don't understand  why did the author assumed the it was always possible that some of the coefficients $a_i$ in a particular representation of $n$ are equal to zero, we may exclude terms that are zero. Thus suppose that
$$n=a_0k^s+a_1k^{s-1}+...+a_{s-t}k^t$$ where neither $a_0\neq 0$ nor $a_{s-t}\neq 0.$

How did he assume such representation in the proof? I am confused with this assumption in the proof. Please help me.

Comment: Some more context might be useful. It seems to me that they are here trying to prove uniqueness, and they will prove existence later

Comment: okay. Are they proving uniqueness here by assuming the existence?

Comment: He's not assuming that any *are* going to be $0$.  He's just acknowledging some *might* be $0$.  If any *are* zero he's... just going to ignore them and rewrite it without the zeros.  He's not assuming any representations actually do exist.  He is going to prove that one always exists and it is the only one.

Comment: He's simply choosing notation that ignores all leading and trailing zero monomials $\,0\cdot k^i.\,$ Clearly deleting summands that equal $0$ does not alter the sum.

Comment: All he is saying is that if we have something like $84,770 = 5\times 7^5 +  0\times 7^4 + 2\times 7^3 + 1\times 7^2 + 0\times 7 + 0$ is a representation he will for the sake of the proof assume this is expressed as $5\times 7^5 + 0\times 7^4 +2\times 7^3 + 1\times 7^2$

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information not otherwise available in your post. [See here for an explanation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the author is doing here is observing that if the first coefficient of a polynomial is non-zero, then among the non-zero coefficients of the polynomial, one of them must come last. Suppose that coefficient is $a_{s-t}$. Then
$$ a_0 k^s + a_1 k^{s-1} + \cdots + a_{s-t} k^t
 =  a_0 k^s + a_1 k^{s-1} + \cdots + a_s $$
where $a_j = 0$ for every integer $j$ such that $s - t < j \leq s.$

Presumably there is a reason later in the proof that we want to give a name to the last non-zero coefficient. That name is $a_{s-t}.$

In the case where $a_s = 0,$ then $t = 0$ and the two polynomials have exactly the same terms. There is no need to assume that the polynomial has any zero terms; the author is simply allowing for the fact that *if* there are any zero terms, some of them might come at the end of the polynomial.

What is not so clear is how we can assume that $n$ has a representation as such a polynomial at all, zero terms or not. Perhaps that too is explained later in the proof. The author might be starting with the uniqueness half of the proof (that is, $b_k(n) \geq 1 \implies b_k(n) = 1$), and following that with the existence proof (that is, the proof that $b_k(n) \geq 1$). All of that would come after the part of the proof that you showed.

Answer (score 1):

You often prove uniqueness with an argument of the form

> *If* X does some job then it's the only thing that does.

You can do that before you know whether or not there is such an X. Sometimes that actually makes the existence proof easier.

Comment: I don't understand. Here the author didn't prove the existence in the proof. But in the statement of the theorem author stated for the proof.

Comment: Is he assume the existence and prove the uniqueness? What if such representation doesn't exist. what is the point of proving existence?

Comment: There would indeed be little point to proving uniqueness for something that doesn't exist. In this case Andrews knows that he can prove both existence and uniqueness and has chosen to prove uniqueness first.

Comment: okay@Ethan Bolkar

Comment: I don't see any answer to the OP's question here.

Comment: @BillDubuque I inferred from the last paragraph of the question and from comments that the apparent existence assumption was what bothered the OP, so addressed that. The OPs comments here suggest that my inference was right.

Comment: I dont agree. Your "answer" has nothing at all to do with the specific question posed in the OP. It might be helpful in understanding the proof as a whole. but that is not what the OP inquired about in the posted question, so it will likely lead to further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT (IT IS NOT AN ASWER!).-Either the author assumes the representation is true (because every easy) or he gives it after of proving unicity for which he takes first the representation whitout the null "digits" to reach after his goal.

Example: For $165_{(3)}=2k^4+0k^3+0k^2+1k+0$ he takes simply
$165_{(3)}=2k^4+1k$ and continue with  his proof of unicity  (which is not show here).

Note that the first "digit" for other representation of $165_{(3)}$ is necessarily $2$.  On the other hand it seems that putting as second term $a_1k^{s-1}$ was not good to write but it would be better $a_rk^{s-r}$ likely as the last term which has be written as $a_{s-t}k^t$ instead of $a_0$